# Simplify toggle and setState updated item's property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Toggling item and changing property's value is very common but I still write this kind of code

```
handleToggle = (id) => {
        const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            if(todo.id === id){ 
                todo.completed = !todo.completed 
            }

            return todo
        })

        this.setState({
            todos: updatedTodos
        })
    }
```

Nothing wrong with it but I found this is the part where I have to write lots of code. Unlike push I can use spread operator, or remove I can simply use one liner filter method. Any idea how can I shorten above code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` to shorten something:

```
handleToggle = (id) => {
    const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo =>
        Object.assign({}, todo, (todo.id === id) ? { completed: !todo.completed } : {}))

    this.setState({
        todos: updatedTodos
    })
}
```

**EDIT**: using short-circuit evaluation instead of ternary operator, you can shorten it a little bit more:

```
handleToggle = (id) => {
    const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo =>
        Object.assign({}, todo, todo.id === id && { completed: !todo.completed }))

    this.setState({
        todos: updatedTodos
    })
}
```

Comment: is the first param, `{}` compulsory?

Comment: Can it be `Object.assign({}, todo, todo.id === id && { completed: !todo.completed }))` ?

Comment: The first parameter is for the target object (check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and it is a mandatory parameter indeed. If we pass todo as first parameter, it will be changed, what might be not desired in terms of "avoid mutation" etc.

Comment: Yes, it can be! I can edit my answer with your own suggestion :p

Comment: @MadelineRies Your suggestion works fine because if we pass `false` (in case for the other todo items) as a source parameter for `Object.assign`, it is ignored! For example: `Object.assign({}, {a: 1}, false)` returns `{a: 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I assume, you just wanna toggle one value in the state array based on the id,

You can make use of `findIndex` ES6 function to get the index and then toggle its value like

```
handleToggle = (id) => {
    var todos = [...this.state.todos];
    var idx = todos.findIndex(obj => obj.id === id);
    todos[idx].completed = !todos[idx].completed;

    this.setState({
        todos
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest, but more readable:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

handleToggle = (index) => {

    var oldTodos = this.state.todos
    var todo = oldTodos[index]

    var todos = update(oldTodos, {
        [index]: {
            completed: {
                $set: !todo.completed
            }
        }
    })

    this.setState({ todos })
}
```

I passed the `index` of item as parameter, not `id`.